# asking Question by " How"

Tags: questions, do-support, subject-auxiliary-inversion

which one is correct?

> How similes have been translated by different translators in this Text?

or

> How do similes have been translated by different translators in this text?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can visit ‎‎[the help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.‎

Comment: In case you hadn't noticed in the answer below by Jim Reynolds:  NEITHER of your examples is correct! Would you like someone to explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How have similes been translated differently by translators in this text?

We can improve its style. For example

> How have multiple  (or various) translators differently translated the similes in this text?

As suggested in the comment below, we can find an alternative to repeating the two forms of *translate* as appropriate to the situation, and produce a more graceful sentence:

- How have different people/experts translated the similes in this text?
- How have different translators approached/handled/processed the similes in the text?

Further, we might make the sentence smoother and easier to read by rearranging some elements and changing focus:

- In this text, how have...?
- In this text, how have different translators differently translated the text's similies?
- In this text, how have people differently translated the text's similies?
- In this text, how have different people translated the text's similies?
- Provide three ways this text has been translated, and explain the differences.

Comment: Also: *In the following text, how have different people translated the similes?*  This format reduces cognitive load by grouping semantic content near it's constituents. It also simplifies the sentence by eliminating the focus of "how they translated it ***differently***" if that is unimportant or not significant enough to mention explicitly.  (I do think it's implied.)  If you want, you can add that to your answer and make a bullet point list of various suggestions.  Others might pipe in with ideas as well. :)

Comment: @Cool I've expanded it. Please be my guest and edit it directly if you'd like!

Comment: I made the following edits: 1. Changed some "quote" notation to "bullet points" 2. Expanded the (last) example of the sentence-template to include "In this text".

Comment: Another idea: *Provide three different ways this text has been translated.* Note the idea of *different people* is implied here.  I suppose that's a general rule for questions like this: "What can be made implicit?" :)